# Substitute for === (case equality operator) in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a rubocop problem while doing my own ruby enumerables. I used a `===` and rubocop is asking me to change it. But every time I try to put something different my method stops working as desired.

```
module Enumerable
  def my_all?(arg = nil)
    return true if !block_given? && include?(nil) == false && include?(false) == false && arg.nil?
    return false unless block_given? || arg.nil? == false || empty?
    
    if block_given?
      my_each do |x|
        return false unless yield(x)
      end
    elsif arg.class == Regexp
      my_each do |x|
        return false unless x.match(arg)
      end
    elsif arg.class == Numeric
      my_each do |x|
        return false unless x.is_a? arg
      end
    else
      my_each do |x|
        return false unless arg === x
      end
    end
    true
  end
end
```

That last `===` is offering resistance to be changed. Thanks to the ones that are able to understand this and help!

Comment: What exactly does Rubocop say?

Comment: What is arg and what is x in that scenario? Is Rubocop suggesting you use a method like `arg.kind_of?(x)`?

Comment: Rubocop just says: Avoid the use of case equality operator. The code works perfectly but it just has this lint error. Arg is the parameters that the method can take and x is the object or the thing that the method iterates with. I'm sorry I'm a beginner and I still don't know how is everything properly called.

Comment: Pay attention here that `1 === Integer`
 => false;
but `Integer === 1`
 => true`

Comment: Some weird things here: `elsif  arg.class == Numeric` means, that arg is an instance of Numeric, but than you try to do `unless x.is_a? arg` that should raise an error, like in case of 
`1.is_a?(1)` => TypeError (class or module required)

Comment: Its inside module Enumerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` method means *is equivalent to*, but `===` is a special purpose one that sometimes means that and more.

For `Class` the `===` method means *is inherited from*, not equivalent to, or in other words the two are the same:

```
  x === y
  x.is_a?(y)
```

Where you'll see how this plays out:

```
  String == String
  # => true
  String === String
  # => false
```

As `String` is a class, it is not a subclass of itself.

That being said, here's a Ruby idiomatic refactoring of your code:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_all?(arg = nil)
    return true if !block_given? && !include?(nil) && !include?(false) && arg.nil?
    return false unless block_given? || !arg.nil? || empty?
    
    if block_given?
      my_each do |x|
        return false unless yield(x)
      end
    else
      case arg
      when Regexp
        my_each do |x|
          return false unless x.match(arg)
        end
      when Numeric
        my_each do |x|
          return false unless x.is_a? arg
        end
      else
        my_each do |x|
          return false unless arg === x
        end
      end
    end

    true
  end
end
```

Where `case` internally uses the `===` method for comparisons so you can easily break out behaviours based on types.

Comment: @Viktor Thanks, fixed.

Comment: `x === y` would be equivalent to `y.is_a?(x)`, isn't it?

Comment: @Ja͢ck Technically, yes, though it's less self-explanatory, especially for JavaScript people who treat `===` as literal equivalence.

Comment: I understand. I'm asking because you reversed the statement in your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

The docs for [`Enumerable#all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#all-3F-method) specifically say that when a pattern is given:

> [...] the method returns whether `pattern === element` for every collection member.

So in order to replicate the method you actually *have* to call `===`. Trying to substitute it just to please Rubocop would likely result in a different behavior.

In your case, I'd [disable the cop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.88/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code) using an inline comment:

```
my_each do |x|
  return false unless arg === x # rubocop:disable Style/CaseEquality
end
```